# Removing app data from sd card on uninstallation of app

Tags: android, emulation, uninstallation, android-sdcard

I am storing some of my app data like videos in external cache directory using the path

```
android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/Android/data/"+getPackag‌​eName()+"/cache/"
```

My expected result is removal of data from this specified path, when I uninstall my app. This is working well when I do it using emulator. The app data is removed from sdcard on uninstalling app. But, in the case, when I execute my code on real device, i.e. Samsung Galaxy S, the app data is not being removed on uninstall. Please, tell me it's possible reason, and how can I overcome this.

I have also tried to find the solution on duplicate threads, but that was of no use.

Comment: when you are removing data from SDCARD?

Comment: I want my data to be removed when I uninstall the app, and hence storing that in external cache in app's package.

Comment: i mean currently where you are calling current code for removing data from SD-CARD ? because you are saying it's working well on emulator.

Comment: use [Context.getExternalFilesDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) it will remove data when app is uninstalled.

Comment: @Prosper: No, actually you didn't get my point. I don't want to remove the data using my code. I just want to store it in suitable location in sd-card, so that, it can be removed automatically on app uninstallation. And, I guess external cache directory is the correct location for that.

Comment: @Shiv: I even tried using Context.getExternalFilesDir, but even its not working on Samsung Galaxy S, where as working fine on emulator.

Comment: check my edited ans : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15803925/1168654

Answer (score 4):

If you're using **API Level 7 or lower**, use `getExternalStorageDirectory()`, **to open a File representing the root of the external storage**. You should then write your data in the following directory:

```
/Android/data/<package_name>/files/
```

The `<package_name>` is your Java-style package name, such as `"com.example.android.app"`. If the user's device is running **API Level 8 or greater** and they **uninstall your application, this directory and all its contents will be deleted.**

for more detail check this **[artical](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)**.

**Edited:**

check this i have just create one file in `/Android/data/com.example.testdir/files/scanned.txt` using below code:

```
package com.example.testdir;

import java.io.File;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void clickBtn(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) {

            File sdcard = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/Android/data/com.example.testdir/files/");

            if (!sdcard.exists())
                sdcard.mkdirs();

            File file = new File(sdcard, "scanned.txt");

            if (!file.exists()) {
                try {
                    file.createNewFile();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and i have also add this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

it remove folder name `<package_name>` in my case folder name is `com.example.testdir` from `sdcard/android/data/com.example.testdir`.

Comment: I have tried that too, but even that is not working in Samsung Galaxy, whereas working in emulator.

Comment: Even, I used the similar code, but as I told you earlier, its not working in samsung galaxy S, but working well in emulator

Comment: This could work if you add android:installLocation="preferExternal" in your manifest file.Basically you will have to set your app install location to external storage.